# Salesforce loading symbol present for long time

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcafe, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to open the Salesforce home page through UI automation (Testcafe), the Salesforce loading symbol is present for long time.
It was worked previously and Sandbox refresh facing this problem.

Not upgraded the Testcafe but now the code is not working[image]

Comment: > the Salesforce loading symbol is present for long time.

If page loading takes much time, just increase the [selector timeout](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402829/guides/basic-guides/element-selectors?search#element-selector-timeout).
If loading hangs completely, please share a simple example where this behavior is reproduced.

Comment: This is still happening even after increase the timeout. I am just entering username and password, after that getting this loading symbol for long time. (Note: Able to access the Salesforce site in Selenium with the same case).